# Is there any pdf reader for Linux that supports layers?

Tags: linux, pdf-viewer

Subject line says it all.  I have a few pdfs that utilize the layers functionality of the portable document format such that not all of the layers are necessarily meant to be rendered or printed together, and proper layer support would entail the ability within the software to selectively enable or disable any of the layer within the document for both on-screen rendering and printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDF Studio Viewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/) is a free PDF reader that works on Linux and that allows to turn on and off layers for rendering. This reader will probably not work for printing as I believe that you will need to edit the layer properties to control its visibility at printing time and will need a PDF editor for that.

Answer (score 0):

PDF Viewer **Evince** support layers since its version GNOME 3.0 from 2014.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Roadmap

PDF Viewer **xpdf** also support layers.
http://www.redfelineninja.org.uk/daniel/2020/08/xpdf-is-a-pdf-viewer-for-gnu-linux-that-supports-layers/